# How to structure/create JSON file for fetching into Backbone Collection

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm learning backbone.js now, and am unfamiliar with JSON files. I would like to fetch a JSON file into a collection, and I would like to know how to structure the JSON file to be fetched.

I've looked absolutely everywhere and can't seem to find an example JSON file specifically for Backbone Collections.

My example data is something like this:

```
id: 1
name: 'Biscuits'
flavour: 'Sweet'

id: 2
name: 'Sushi'
flavour: 'Savoury'
```

How do I turn that data into the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "..."}, {"id":2,"name":"..."}]
```

And so on.
collections in backbone.js assume that json data will be a list with individual objects from which models will be constructed.